# How to make a plugin require another plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm building a plugin that adds extra functionality to a main plugin. Ideally in the plugins administration screen, the "activate" link should be disabled and an inline note should be added that tells the user to install and activate the main plugin first before he/she can use the current plugin.

Comment: What about using: is_plugin_active() ?

eg:

    `if (is_plugin_active('path/to/plugin.php')) {
    // Do something
    }`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys. Though both answers set me on the right path, none worked out of the box. So I'm sharing my solutions below.

### Method 1 - Using register_activation_hook:

Create the Parent Plugin in plugins/parent-plugin/parent-plugin.php:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Parent Plugin
Description: Demo plugin with a dependent child plugin.
Version: 1.0.0
*/
```

Create the Child Plugin in plugins/child-plugin/child-plugin.php:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Child Plugin
Description: Parent Plugin should be installed and active to use this plugin.
Version: 1.0.0
*/
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'child_plugin_activate' );
function child_plugin_activate(){

    // Require parent plugin
    if ( ! is_plugin_active( 'parent-plugin/parent-plugin.php' ) and current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) {
        // Stop activation redirect and show error
        wp_die('Sorry, but this plugin requires the Parent Plugin to be installed and active. <br><a href="' . admin_url( 'plugins.php' ) . '">&laquo; Return to Plugins</a>');
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm not using `deactivate_plugins( $plugin );` as for some reason it does not work. So I used wp_die to cancel the activation redirection and inform the user.

**Advantage:**

- Simple solution and does not incur additional db hits compared to method 2

**Disadvantages:**

- wp_die screen is ugly
- wp_die screen will STILL show up if you activated the Parent Plugin and Child Plugin at the same time using the checkboxes in the plugins admin screen.

### Method 2 - Using admin_init and admin_notices

Create the Parent Plugin in plugins/parent-plugin/parent-plugin.php:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Parent Plugin
Description: Demo plugin with a dependent child plugin.
Version: 1.0.0
*/
```

Create the Child Plugin in plugins/child-plugin/child-plugin.php:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Child Plugin
Description: Parent Plugin should be installed and active to use this plugin.
Version: 1.0.0
*/
add_action( 'admin_init', 'child_plugin_has_parent_plugin' );
function child_plugin_has_parent_plugin() {
    if ( is_admin() && current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) &&  !is_plugin_active( 'parent-plugin/parent-plugin.php' ) ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'child_plugin_notice' );

        deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ); 

        if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) {
            unset( $_GET['activate'] );
        }
    }
}

function child_plugin_notice(){
    ?><div class="error"><p>Sorry, but Child Plugin requires the Parent plugin to be installed and active.</p></div><?php
}
```

**Advantage:**

- Works when you activate the Parent and Child plugin at the same time using checkboxes

**Disadvantage:**

- Incur additional db hits as the plugin is actually activated at first and deactivated once admin_init runs.

As for my question regarding disabling the activate link, I could use:

```
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links', 'disable_child_link', 10, 2 );
function disable_child_link( $links, $file ) {

    if ( 'child-plugin/child-plugin.php' == $file and isset($links['activate']) )
        $links['activate'] = '<span>Activate</span>';

    return $links;
}
```

However, it turned out to be highly impractical as there is NO place to put this code. I could not put it on the parent plugin as the parent plugin should be active for this code to run. Certainly does not belong to child plugin or functions.php. So I'm scrapping this idea.

Comment: Method 2 worked great! I used it to extend someone else's plugin.

Comment: Can I also use this to require plugins from the Wordpress plugin directory? I want to create a job posting plugin, but use an existing forms-plugin (like Formidable or Caldera Forms) to create the application form.

Answer (score 6):

Both of the suggested solutions have flaws.

**Method 1:** As mentioned, wp_die() screen will STILL show up when the Parent Plugin and Child Plugin activated at the same time using the checkboxes in the plugins admin screen.

**Method 2:** In some use-cases it's not good since 'admin_init' is executed way after 'plugins_loaded' (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), and after the uninstallation hook (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook). So for example, if we do want the add-on to run some code on uninstallation whether the parent plugin is active or not, this approach will NOT work.

**Solution:**

First of all, we need to append the following code to the end of the parent plugin's main PHP file:

```
do_action( 'my_plugin_loaded' );
```

This will dispatch an event/signal to all subscribers, telling that the core plugin was loaded.

Then, the add-on's class should look like the following:

```
class My_Addon
{
    static function init ()
    {
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( __CLASS__, '_install' ) );

        if ( ! self::_is_parent_active_and_loaded() ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    #region Parent Plugin Check

    /**
     * Check if parent plugin is activated (not necessarly loaded).
     *
     * @author Vova Feldman (@svovaf)
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    static function _is_parent_activated()
    {
        $active_plugins_basenames = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
        foreach ( $active_plugins_basenames as $plugin_basename ) {
            if ( false !== strpos( $plugin_basename, '/my-plugin-main-file.php' ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check if parent plugin is active and loaded.
     *
     * @author Vova Feldman (@svovaf)
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    static function _is_parent_active_and_loaded()
    {
        return class_exists( 'My_Plugin' );
    }

    /**
     *
     * @author Vova Feldman (@svovaf)
     */
    static function _install()
    {
        if ( ! self::_is_parent_active_and_loaded() ) {
            deactivate_plugins( basename( __FILE__ ) );

            // Message error + allow back link.
            wp_die( __( 'My Add-on requires My Plugin to be installed and activated.' ), __( 'Error' ), array( 'back_link' => true ) );
        }
    }

    #endregion Parent Plugin Check
}

if (My_Addon::_is_parent_active_and_loaded())
{
    // If parent plugin already included, init add-on.
    My_Addon::init();
}
else if (My_Addon::_is_parent_activated())
{
    // Init add-on only after the parent plugins is loaded.
    add_action( 'my_plugin_loaded', array( __CLASS__, 'init' ) );
}
else
{
    // Even though the parent plugin is not activated, execute add-on for activation / uninstall hooks.
    My_Addon::init();
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This answer has a flaw too. :-) It assumes that you have full control over the parent plugin where you can add do_action( 'my_plugin_loaded' ); in its code. The selected answer will work with or without control of the parent plugin (e.g. the parent plugin is not yours)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. In my case, I *do* have full control over the parent plugin, and needed to create this kind of dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out, it's commented, so that should help you understand it.

```
<?php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' ); // Register myplugin_activate on
function myplugin_activate() {
    $plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ ); // 'myplugin'
    if ( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory/first-plugin.php' ) ) {
        // Plugin was active, do hook for 'myplugin'
    } else {
        // Plugin was not-active, uh oh, do not allow this plugin to activate
        deactivate_plugins( $plugin ); // Deactivate 'myplugin'
    }
}
?>
```

If this throws out an error, you could also check the 'option' of 'myplugin' and set it to false or not activated.

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress version 6.5, you can define plugin dependencies inside the main plugin file with the `Requires Plugins` header. For example:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin
 * Requires Plugins: plugin-one, plugin-two
 */
```

Simply add a comma-separated list of plugin slugs from the WP.org repo, and you're good to go.

Dependencies are listed in the plugin's card itself, in `Plugins → All Plugins`, and `Plugins → Add New` screens.

Plugins not hosted on WordPress.org can also be listed, but they need to be installed manually.

Note that this won't work for themes, only plugins. Also, you can't define specific plugin versions, and all plugins will be required. There's no way to require only one of the listed plugins.

Read the entire announcement of this feature in the [related blog post from make.wordpress.org](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2024/03/05/introducing-plugin-dependencies-in-wordpress-6-5/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need **TGM Plugin Activation**.

> [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com) is a PHP library that allows you to easily
>   require or recommend plugins for your WordPress themes (and plugins).
>   It allows your users to install, update and even automatically
>   activate plugins in singular or bulk fashion using native WordPress
>   classes, functions and interfaces. You can reference bundled plugins,
>   plugins from the WordPress Plugin Repository or even plugins hosted
>   elsewhere on the internet.