# Woocommerce dependent plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to create an custom plugin for woocommerce features so it is a dependent plugin so i need trigger an error that it requires woocommerce plugin and the plugin should not be activated if woocommerce plugin is not activated, please help

Comment: I expect there are plenty of existing plugins that do this that you can copy? I'd add an admin_init hook that checks if one of the WooCommerce classes exists - I'm not sure which to recommend - and if not add an admin_notices hook to output some warning HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a plugin require another plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127818/how-to-make-a-plugin-require-another-plugin)